# Create a stdout text view in a python app

Tags: python, textview, gtk, stdout

In python with gtk library used for creating windows, how can I redirect stdout in real time to a specified textview buffer?

```
    self.textbuffer.set_text(sys.stdout)
```

I see that subprocess allows that, but it needs another process to run, I want to capture the output of the print commands already present in the rest of the program (current process not another process)

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
import sys

class MyStdout:
    def __init__(self, buffer):
        self.buffer = buffer

    def write(self, string):
       if string:
           # Append self.buffer

sys.stdout = MyStdout(self.textbuffer)
```

Comment: I seem to understand that you mean to assign something to stdout? What I would like is to retreive information that goes to a terminal.

Comment: Terminals get stdout and stderr, so that would be this.

Comment: Ok thanks, excuse me but I'll wait until I understand your reply before voting for it.